# SPARQL: find objects with all sub-objects matching a criteria

Tags: sparql, rdf

Given this data, where each person may optionally have a "smart" predicate, and each department may have zero or more people, I need to find departments that contain only the smart people. The result should only include departments 1 and 2.  Ideally, the result should also include the "smart" objects for each department.  Thanks!

```
person:A  p:type  'p' ;
          p:smart 'yes' .
person:B  p:type  'p' ;
          p:smart 'maybe' .
person:C  p:type  'p' .

department:1   p:type 'd' ;
               p:has  person:A, person:B .
department:2   p:type 'd' ;
               p:has  person:B .
department:3   p:type 'd' ;
               p:has  person:B, person:C .
department:4   p:type 'd' .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling I've answered something similar before, but anyway there is a reasonably nice way to do this:

```sql
select ?dept 
   (count(?person) as ?pc) (count(?smart) as ?sc)
   (group_concat(?smart; separator=',') as ?smarts)
{
    ?dept p:has ?person .
    optional { ?person p:smart ?smart }
}
group by ?dept
having (?pc = ?sc)
```

That is: find the departments, people, and (where available) smart value. For each department find ones where the number of people matches the number of smart values.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| dept                              | pc | sc | smarts      |
=============================================================
| <http://example.com/department#2> | 1  | 1  | "maybe"     |
| <http://example.com/department#1> | 2  | 2  | "yes,maybe" |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

When you want to get results for each object, matching some criteria, `group by` / `having` is often the cleanest answer (in that you can separate out matching from filtering).

Comment: I really like this solution! I'm wondering which one is generally faster, but maybe there isn't that much difference. When I've time I'll try it out in some kind of small "benchmark". Cheers

Comment: I should point out that this solution relies on there bring at most one smart value per-person. It's not hard to solve more complex cases, but they are less pretty (the aggregate / having clauses get longer). As for speed, I suspect there isn't much difference for most sane stores (i.e. they do the filter joins in a sane order), but it would be interesting to test.

Comment: Well at least now your answer is the accepted one, so maybe there are some advantages. Would be interesting to know which ones :D

Answer (score 3):

Something like double-negation might work:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?dept WHERE {
  ?dept p:has ?person .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
  ?dept p:has ?person1 .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
     ?person1 p:smart ?smartVal
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```sql
+---------------+
|     dept      |
+---------------+
|  department:1 |
|  department:2 |
+---------------+
```

With values:

```sql
SELECT ?dept (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?smart;separator=";") as ?smartValues) WHERE {
  ?dept p:has ?person .
  ?person p:smart ?smart
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
  ?dept p:has ?person1 .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
     ?person1 p:smart ?smartVal
    }
  }
}
GROUP BY ?dept
```

Result:

```sql
+---------------+-------------+
|     dept      | smartValues |
+---------------+-------------+
|  department:1 | maybe;yes   |
|  department:2 | maybe       |
+---------------+-------------+
```